# Is my beer dunkelweizen style?

Tags: beer-styles

I tried to make dunkelweizen style beer but it became maybe a with higher alcohol content. And now I think it is not the style I wanted.

The ingredients:

- Wheat Malt pale - 1kg
- Munich Malt Type 1 - 0.4kg
- CARAFA® Special Type 1 - 0.1kg
- hops - HALLERTAU Trad. - 5g
- yeast - Safbrew WB-06 - 11g

Mashing water was 5 liters for 1 hour with varying temperature between 60 C and 75 C.

Then I added 1 liter water.

Gravity before boiling was 16.

Boiling 1 hour.

2.5 grams hops added 15 minutes after start of boiling and the other 2.5 grams 10 minutes before the end of boiling.

Gravity after boiling was 17.2

Fermentation for 3 weeks ant about 20 - 21 C.

I don't remember the gravity after fermentation, but for sure know that the online calculators gave me ABV 7.9

I don't know how to measure the bitterness and color. The beer is a little bit more bitter for my taste, but my friends say it is not too bitter. The beer has some strawberry and black olive flavor and interesting aroma. I drink homemade beer for first time and I actually don't know what to expect.

Given the information above can someone tell me if is it dunkelweizen or if not then what style of beer is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the 2015 BJCP description which a dunkleweisse is judged against.

**Impression**
A moderately dark German wheat beer with a distinctive banana-and-clove yeast character, supported by a toasted bread or caramel malt flavor. Highly carbonated and refreshing, with a creamy, fluffy texture and light finish that encourages drinking.

**Aroma**
Moderate phenols (usually clove) and fruity esters (usually banana). The balance and intensity of the phenol and ester components can vary but the best examples are reasonably balanced. Optionally, a low to moderate vanilla character and/or faint bubblegum notes may be present, but should not dominate. Hop aroma ranges from low to none, and may be lightly floral, spicy, or herbal. A light to moderate wheat aroma (which might be perceived as bready, doughy or grainy) may be present and is often accompanied by a caramel, bread crust, or richer malt aroma. The malt aroma may moderate the phenols and esters somewhat.

**Appearance**
Light copper to mahogany brown in color. A very thick, moussy, long-lasting off-white head is characteristic. The high protein content of wheat impairs clarity in this traditionally unfiltered style, although the level of haze is somewhat variable. Suspended yeast sediment can contribute to cloudiness.

**Flavor**
Low to moderately strong banana and clove flavor. The balance and intensity of the phenol and ester components can vary but the best examples are reasonably balanced and fairly prominent. Optionally, a very light to moderate vanilla character and/or faint bubblegum notes can accentuate the banana flavor, sweetness and roundness; neither should be dominant if present. The soft, somewhat bready, doughy, or grainy flavor of wheat is complementary, as is a richer caramel, toast, or bread crust flavor. The malty richness can be low to medium-high, and supports the yeast character. A roasted malt character is inappropriate. A spicy, herbal, or floral hop flavor is very low to none, and hop bitterness is very low to low. Well-rounded, flavorful, often somewhat malty palate with a relatively dry finish.

**Mouthfeel**
Medium-light to medium-full body. The texture of wheat as well as yeast in suspension imparts the sensation of a fluffy, creamy fullness that may progress to a lighter finish, aided by moderate to high carbonation. Effervescent.

**Comments**
The presence of Munich and/or Vienna-type barley malts gives this style a deep, rich barley malt character not found in a weissbier. Often known as Dunkelweizen , particularly in the United States.

**History**
Bavaria has a wheat beer brewing traditional hundreds of years old, but the brewing right was reserved for Bavarian royalty until the late 1700s. Old-fashioned Bavarian wheat beer was often dark, as were most beer of the day. Pale weissbier started to become popular in the 1960s, but traditional dark wheat beer remained somewhat of an old person’s drink.

**Ingredients**
By German brewing tradition, at least 50% of the grist must be malted wheat, although some versions use up to 70%; the remainder is usually Munich, Vienna, or dark or caramel wheat malts, or Pilsner malt with color malt. A decoction mash is traditional, but infrequently used today. Weizen ale yeasts produce the typical spicy and fruity character, although extreme fermentation temperatures can affect the balance and produce off-flavors.

**Comparison**
Reflecting the best yeast and wheat character of a weissbier blended with the malty richness of a Munich dunkel. The banana and clove character is often less apparent than in a weissbier due to the increased maltiness.

**Examples**
Ayinger Ur-Weisse, Ettaler Weissbier Dunkel, Franziskaner Hefe-Weisse Dunkel, Hacker-Pschorr Weisse Dark, Tucher Dunkles Hefe Weizen, Weihenstephaner Hefeweissbier Dunkel

**Vital Statistics**

IBUs: 10 - 18

OG: 1.044 - 1.056

ABV: 4.3 - 5.6

FG: 1.010 - 1.014

Comment: Thanks, very useful, now I know I have to search for "BJCP description" for other styles.

Comment: Now I understand , my beer is more like Weizenbock

Comment: @vladiz BJCP.org has a free style guide download, also a couple in the app stores.